# Sorting list of objects from another Class with lambda in Java

Tags: java, sorting

In my taks I need to sort names with lambda. Class lambdaComparator extends class Car.

I make class LambdaComparator like this:

```
public class LambdaComparator extends Car

public LambdaComparator(String name) {super(name);}
```

In this class I need to sort objects of type Car.

In main class I have list of objects and with function I need to sort it.

In class LambdaComparator I have this:

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Car>() {
         public int compare(Car x, Car y) {
            return x.getName().compareTo(y.getName()));
         }
      });
```

How should I call function in main to get this sorted, should I make function of type void in class to somehow call it.

Edit: lambda expression

```
class LambdaSort<T extends Car>
private List<T> listOfCars;

public LambdaComparator(){
this.listOfCars = new ArrayList<T>();
}

 public void sortCars(T cars)
listOfCars.sort((Car o1, Car o2)->o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
```

In main function I add objects of type car to that list.

Comment: That's not a lambda Comparator.  It is simply an instance of an anonymous class.

Comment: Im new to lambdas so I dont know how to use them properly

Answer (score 2):

A lambda comparator would be something like this.

```
Comparator<Car> comp = (c1, c2)-> c1.getName().compareTo(c2.getName());
```

In the above example, the Comparator is comparing on a specific field of the `Car` class, `name`.  Since name probably returns a string, one can use `compareTo` since the String class implements the `Comparable` (not `Comparator`) interface for comparing Strings.

But the lambda could be specified much more easily using one of the methods in the Comparator interface.  The `comparing` method may take a lambda or a method reference (shown below).

```
Comparator<Car> comp = Comparator.comparing(Car::getName);
```

Then when it is passed to the sort method, the sort method will apply it to the objects under sort as `comp.compare(obj1, obj2)` (although it may not be called `comp` in the method that uses it)

For more information, check out [The Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html)

Comment: I need to do it with lambda

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at what lambda is [here](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_lambda.asp).

If you have a list in your main class, it's as simple as just sorting it. You probably don't even need the class `LambdaComparator`.

```
        List<Car> list = new ArrayList<>();
        Collections.sort(list, (a, b) -> a.getName().compareTo(b.getName()));
```

Comment: I need to do it in class

Comment: @sdavb Provide more code in your question and maybe I can help you.